# Missing packages imutils in ipython

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I was trying to run a  python script (recognize.py) which is in my ipython  folder  . Hence I created a main ipython notebook which has the following contents:

```
%run recognize --training images/training --testing images/testing
```

However I got this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\asd\local-binary-patterns\local-binary-patterns\recognize.py in <module>()
      5 from pyimagesearch.localbinarypatterns import LocalBinaryPatterns
      6 from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
----> 7 from imutils import paths
      8 import argparse
      9 import cv2

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imutils'
```

Is it possible that jupyter notebook can have some msising packages  in this case : imutils? How can  a missing package be installed in jupyter notebook?

Or is this error something else that I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try these steps

```
import pip  
pip.main(['install', 'imutils'])
```